# Exibir Dados em Div Pulando Linha

Tags: javascript

Eu preciso exibir o resultado do laço `FOR` em uma `DIV`, pulando linha, como eu posso fazer?

Exemplo

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Meu Código:

```
for(i = 0; i <= keyCliente; i++){
    document.getElementById("divExibir").innerHTML = i;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens duas opões, ou usas um `<br>` que faz exatamente "quebra de linha" ou colocas esse conteúdo dentro de um elemento bloco, como o `p`. Ou outro elemento qualquer não "bloco" mas com `display: block` no css.

Nota:

- tens de usar `+=` para evitar estar sempre a apagar e escrever por cima dentro do loop. Com o `+=` ele vai acrescentando.
- muda o `document.getElementById('divExibir');` para fora do loop. Essa linha atrasa o código.

### Usando `<br>`:

```
var keyCliente = 5;
var divExibir = document.getElementById("divExibir")
for (var i = 1; i <= keyCliente; i++) {
    divExibir.innerHTML += i + '<br>';
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/euerct5u/3/

### Usando `<p>`:

```
var keyCliente = 5;
var divExibir = document.getElementById("divExibir")
for (var i = 1; i <= keyCliente; i++) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = i;
    divExibir.appendChild(p);
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/euerct5u/4/

ou, alternativa:

```
var keyCliente = 5;
var divExibir = document.getElementById("divExibir")
for (var i = 1; i <= keyCliente; i++) {
    divExibir.innerHTML += '<p>' + i + '</p>';
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/euerct5u/5/

Answer (score 1):

Você pode resolver isso da seguinte maneira:

```
document.getElementById("divExibir").innerHTML = document.getElementById("divExibir").innerHTML + i + '<br>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando você usa innerHTML você substitui a cada loop tudo que está dentro da div e coloca o novo conteúdo. Ou seja quando passa pelo primeiro loop ele adicionava o número 1, quando passava pelo segundo loop, ele zera a div e adicionava o 2 e assim por diante, abaixo segue exemplo de como conservar o conteúdo original e adicionar um novo em seguida. Somei com um `<br />` para quebrar a linha.

```
<script>
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var div = document.getElementById('divExibir');

    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + i + '<br />';
  }
</script>
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677799/how-to-append-data-to-div-using-javascript)