# Qual a melhor forma de interagir Javascript com uma query em PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Olá

Eu tenho uma função em javascript que lê o localStorage do navegador que representa o ID do cliente e exibe em uma DIV o resultado da leitura do localStorage. Eu gostaria que o javascript traga os ID's dos clientes alocado nolocalStorage e colete do banco de dados utilizando uma query PHP o nome e dados gerais do cliente, na medida que o laço FOR vai sendo executado.

Mas eu nunca fiz isso antes, qual a melhor forma de ser fazer isso, da forma correta. Se possivel, me dê um exemplo.

Eu cheguei até aqui:

```
function listarClientes()
{

  for(i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
  {
    // Retrieve
  var divInformacoesClientes = document.getElementById("divCliente");
  divInformacoesClient.innerHTML += '<p>' + localStorage.getItem(i); + '</p>';

  }

}
```

Codigo atual com a requisição AJAX.

```
  $.get("carrinho_compras.php",
  {id:compras_no_carrinho},
  function(data)
  {
    //alert(data);
    console.log(data);
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML += data ;
  }, "html");
```

Codigo PHP

```
<?php

include 'include/connection.php';

$id = $_GET['id'];

$query = "SELECT id, imagem, produto FROM produtos WHERE id = $id ORDER BY id ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row[2];
}
?>
```

Erro que esta sendo exibido ao inserir  ( += ) para concatenar todos os valores recebidos pela requisição AJAX.

```
 Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\projetos\PaperList\carrinho_compras.php on line 11
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Recomendo pensar numa outra maneira, puxando os dados da `localStorage` com `javascript` pra chamar uma pagina do servidor, so consigo imaginar esse procedimento usando `ajax`, e isso geraria múltiplas chamadas `ajax` pra cada item do laço de repetição..... dependendo da quantidade pode acabar por ser bem demorado.

Comment: Não pode carregar esses dados de uma vez só quando a pagina é executada?

Comment: Então, estou fazendo um carrinho de compras e a medida que apessoa vai comprando vai adiacionando no carrinho, no caso no localStorage, esta funcionado muito bem, apenas preciso pegar os dados dos produtos e do cliente com uma query em php O sistema esta pronto, não quero ter de mudar tudo. Talvez eu tenha que utilizar prototype.

Comment: A sim, de uma olhada em chamadas utilizando [ajax](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax) :)

Comment: Seria isso ? $.ajax({type:'get';
         url:'numero.php',
         success: function(i){$('table tr').html('<td>'+i+'</td>')}

Comment: Mais ou menos, depois quando tiver mais tempo respondo, se alguém não responder antes

Comment: No cso eu terei uma pagina em PHP com a query e o ajax vai nessa pagina e mostra o retorno da pagina. Como o GEt do prototype.

Comment: Vejo que acabaste usando `<p></p>` como sugeri na [outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/160609/129), podes sempre dar um voto de agradecimento já que não marcaste como resposta certa. Digo não só para mim, mas como prática com os outros elementos da comunidade.

Comment: Desculpe, li correndo sua resposta, vou dar o voto de agredecimento. Obrigado

Comment: Sabes como fazer `echo` no PHP se fôr chamado o ficheiro PHP com `ficheiro?id=21` por exemplo?

Comment: Então, eu já consegui fazer a requisição Ajax, mas quando eu insiro += para concatenar todos os valores recebido pela requisição AJAX enviada pela pagina PHP, da um erro estranho do mysqli. Eu atualizei meu post acima.

Comment: Esse erro do `mysqli_fetch_array` não tem a ver com o que está no código do ajax success. Podes colocar o código PHP que tens?

Comment: Então, o estranho é que somente da erro, quando eu insiro o ( += ) quando eu insiro apenas o ( = ), funciona normalmente. Alterei meu post lá em cima.

Comment: Vale notar que tem um erro aqui: `localStorage.getItem(i); + '</p` Esse `;` aí no meio não tem sentido.

Comment: Sobre o erro da questão, já foi respondido: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28184/70 - seguindo os passos da resposta, vai encontrar a razão do erro.

Comment: Legal, faltou o - or die(mysql_error()) - Obrigado a todos que me ajudaram, vocês são nota 10.